# How to guarantee if a real function is $C^\infty$ without using $f^{(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know that function $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ is $C^\infty$ but I wanna prove that.

**Question**

Is there something that I could use to guarantee this without actually calculating $f^{(n)}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the sum of a trivially $\mathcal C^\infty$ function and the reciprocal of another  $\mathcal C^\infty$ function which never vanishes. The rules of computation of the derivative of a reciprocal show this reciprocal is also  $\mathcal C^\infty$.